# breakpoints in Dartium do not work in the package section

Tags: dart

I am running a dart web site using the 'pub serv' command.
I would like to debug the web site using dartium.

I can get **Dartium** devtools to stop on a breakpoint if it is added to code in index.main file.

I cannot get Dartium to stop on a breakpoint if it is added to code in the packages section.

All the plugins are disabled.

How can I enable debugging of libraries?

Comment: What is "packages section"? Can you navigate to the code from `index.main.dart` to the code in the library, set the breakpoint there and then try again if it stops at the breakpoint?

Comment: Run up Dartium, Right click, inspect element. open sources tag. tree on LHS, localhost:8080/packages/nameofmypackage open source file, add breakpoint that is ignored. localhost:8080/packages/index.dart - open file and add breakpoint this is ignored

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you debug directly in WebStorm. Didn't read the question properly. see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this is but if you look up the source in `(no domain)` > `package:nameofmypackage` breakpoints work.